# sh: bundle: error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, capistrano

I'm really frustrated - issue of capistrano not finding bundle has alot of questions & answers. but they don't seem to work for me... so sad :(
situation is - i'm using host which has system wide rvm installed.

```
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.2.4

$ rvm -v
rvm 1.18.8 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [i686-linux]
```

and error is it can't execute `sh: bundle`: http://community.webfaction.com/questions/5186/capistrano-cant-find-bundle
Ive tried setting rvm variables

```
  set :rvm_ruby_string, "1.9.3"
    set :rake,            "rvm use #{rvm_ruby_string} do bundle exec rake"
    set :bundle_cmd,      "rvm use #{rvm_ruby_string} do bundle "
```

Then i tried setting :default_environment like so http://community.webfaction.com/questions/5186/capistrano-cant-find-bundle

Tried setting to combined output of `which ruby` & `ecno $HOME` it still doesn't work.
Any ideas? The problem seems quite widespread... but i can't fix it!

**UPDATE 1**
tried using rvm solution https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/

> set :default_environment, {
>   'PATH' =>"/home/h41319/data/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin/bundle::/home/h41319/data/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin/ruby:PATH",
>   'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby 1.9.3',
>      'GEM_HOME'     => '/home/h41319/data/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385',
>     'GEM_PATH'     =>
>   '/home/h41319/data/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global',
>   'BUNDLE_PATH' => '/home/h41319/data/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin/bundle'  # If you are using bundler. }

No luck !

Comment: Can be some issues with your paths. I am not too familiar with the paths on linux, so I really can't help you too much. On windows you would set a system variable and add something like this "....; C:/path/to/ruby/bin;" then you are a small reboot/restart of terminal away from happiness.

Comment: is it working without capistrano?

Comment: I can check versions of ruby and bundler over ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on rvm-capistrano gem, the documentation should be clear about how to use it => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#readme

Comment: thanks, found useful, but misunderstanding with examples https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano/issues/55

Comment: yeah, there is updated documentation in a branch https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano/blob/feature/readme_for_1.3.0/README.md but it will get outdated in few days so I did not wanted to mention it here to not confuse anyone